# Field required depending on the value of an other field with JSF2 / PF4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2 with Primefaces 4 on a Tomcat 7.
I have a form in which certains fields are required depending on the value of a checkbox. So In the example below, the fields in the fieldset are required only if the checkbox is checked (which is, by default) :

```xml
<h:form id="formId">
    ...
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="fieldId1" value="#{myBean.firm}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this :formId:fieldsetId" update="@this :formId:fieldsetId"/>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    ...
    <p:fieldset id="fieldsetId">
        <p:inputText id="field2" value="#{myBean.field2Value}" required="#{myBean.firm}"/>
        <p:inputText id="field3" value="#{myBean.field3Value}" required="#{myBean.firm}"/>
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

My problem is that the ajax request passes through the validation, so when i unchecked the checkbox, the validation fails on the inputFields if they are not filled, and the model is not updated.
So my attribute *firm* is still set to true in *myBean* and my inputText fields are still required.

At first I forgot to process the fieldset

```xml
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this :formId:fieldsetId"/>
```

This worked, or I though, but as the field are not processed, if I filled some fields before unchecking the box, all the data were lost. Setting immediate="true" won't work either in that case.

It seems to me to be a very simple and common usecase, and I can't believe there is not a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, that did the trick ! A big thanks also for all your great replies and tutorials !

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

```
<h:form id="formId">
        ...
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="fieldId1" value="#{myBean.firm}">
            <f:ajax listener="#{bean.checkBoxListener}" immediate="true" update=":formId:fieldsetId" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        ...
        <p:fieldset id="fieldsetId">
            <p:inputText id="field2" value="#{myBean.field2Value}" required="#{myBean.firm}"/>
            <p:inputText id="field3" value="#{myBean.field3Value}" required="#{myBean.firm}"/>
        </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

in the bean

```
public void checkBoxListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    this.firm = (Boolean) ((UIInput) event.getComponent()).getValue();
}
```

Comment: If you can't write code off top of head, please actually run and test it before doing it off as an answer.